# Iterate though keys RestKit iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapping, restkit

How can I map this using RestKit? I want to generalize this as much as possible because each key represents the name of a Parking Lot and if any parking lot is added I don't need to change the code.

```
{
    Arco Do Cego: 
        {
            address: "Parque do Arco Cego, Avenida JoÃ£o CrisÃ³stomo, 1000-178 Lisboa",
            campus: "Alameda",
            description: "Parque Estacionamento do Arco do Cego",
            freeSlots: 68,
            latlng: "38.73640895,-9.14313902",
            name: "Arco do Cego",
            total: 70,
            workingHours: "24h"
        }
}
```

And I wanted something like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(ParkingSpots)
class ParkingSpots: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var parks: NSSet

}

@objc(Park)
class Park: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var address: String
    @NSManaged var campus: String
    @NSManaged var desc: String
    @NSManaged var freeSlots: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var latlng: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var total: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var workingHours: String
    @NSManaged var parkingSpot: ParkingSpots
}
```

In Java I would:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jObj.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    Parking parking = gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), Parking.class);
    parking.setName(name);
}
```

Thank you. I am using iOS8 and swift

Comment: Below discussion might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690489/how-to-add-objects-of-entity-classdtos-value-using-addattributemappings-in/44775328#44775328

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:` which allows you to extract that key and use it as a value. So in this case you wouldn't use the name from the dictionary, you would use the key to map yo the name.